# If I am going to dabble in the world of music, what aspect should I train more to build a solid base, and thus obtain better results(?)

Tags: theory, technique, voice, terminology

Good morning, I think I summarized it pretty well in the question, however, I mean exactly that "push" that a beginner must have, something that avoids excessive stumbles in their learning, of course I know perfectly well that everything is worked and results are obtained with effort and determination and that there will always be bad days, but I think it would be great to have this information in question, different opinions, nourish more and better my knowledge in this wonderful world. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What would you classify as a "solid base" - work ethic, talent, or both? Stronger willpower can improve work ethic, for example, and a better knowledge of music theory can build talent, so to speak.

Comment: I've submitted an edit of your question which I hope will be approved, but it would be good to have some more details about what types of musical situations you envision to play in? Do you want to be all round good? Playing blues, rock, classical...? Playing solo, groups or both?

Answer (score 3):

Keep a practice book.  In it goes:

- A log of your practice sessions, with what you practiced, where you think you did well, and where you need more work.  Example: "20 minutes of major scales, by 4ths, at 120 BPM.  Needs more work at this speed before going faster.
- Notes about where you left off in an instructional book: "Up to page 22 of the intro book.  Working on the exercise at the top of the page.  Need to ask the teacher about the 4th measure."
- Notes on things you want to refer back to, such as chord diagrams, progressions, etc.
- Lists of tunes you've heard that you want to learn.
- If you are taking lessons, then notes from those lessons.  What did your teacher show you, what are you supposed to be practicing?
- Anything else you don't want to forget.

Practice time is probably our most valuable commodity when learning music, so using it more effectively is a big deal.  A practice book can make practice much more effective.